# In JavaScript when does a function become a method?

Tags: javascript, methods

In JavaScript does a function become a method when added as a property on an object, or is it the *invocation* of a function against an object that makes it a method?

Comment: The snarky answer is "when the blog post author decides upon the word to use." The language itself doesn't make any formal distinction; a function is a function. I use "method" when I'm writing about a function and want to clarify that what I'm describing only makes sense when the function is *used as* a "method" via an object reference. *edit* of course Quentin posts chapter and verse :)

Comment: May this help: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

Comment: @Pointy as Quentin's answer shows there actually _is_ a formal definition.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes I should have predicted that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.27) is:

> function that is the value of a property

Comment: Good answer from the spec, consider adding details.

Comment: This might be how the spec defines it, but I don't think they picked a useful definition. Suppose I define a global function `f` in my browser's console. `window.f` is that function, so the function is the value of a property, and by this definition, it's a method, but I'm never going to call it as `window.f`.

Comment: I suppose functions defined on objects are methods, but those methods can be invoked as methods on other objects, or indeed as bare functions (i.e. an invocation of a method, not as a method)

Comment: @BenAston the term, even if it's in the spec, is clearly less "solid" than a term like "function". A function that's a "method" may or may not *always* be a method, and in fact the function itself has no way to determine whether it's a "method"!

Comment: @Pointy Hence my question suggesting that the invocation be the determiner. The spec says a function as a property value is a method. Thus, I guess methods in JS, like you say may be invoked as plain old functions. e.g. `var o = { foo() {} }; var p = o.foo; p();`

Comment: This might change with ES6.

Answer (score -1):

Since every function is javascript is part of an object, technically they are all methods.

Personally I would put the difference on binding to an object, if you're binding a function to a specific scope, it's a method.

Comment: Not every function is part of an object in JavaScript. `(function(){ /* what object am I a part of? */})())`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: it's always a method of your current scope. For example: `function x(){}; console.log(this.x);`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: after the edit, that's an anonymous method which is part of the anonymous scope you created within the `(...)`. Just because the scope is inaccessible doesn't change the fact that it's part of the scope :)

Comment: @Wolph I encourage you to try that out for real. The value of `this` is **not** a reference to the current scope.

Comment: It's part of the environment but it's not part of any object. Also, your `this` example is wrong and only works for the global scope and in loose mode.

Comment: The point is, every javascript is bound to some scope, therefore making it a method. Regardless of the examples. @pointy: tried in nose and chrome, works fine ;)

Comment: @Wolph your assertion is true but it doesn't really mean anything; a scope is *not* the same as an object. You cannot, for example, force a function to be invoked such that `this` references some non-global scope.

Comment: @Pointy: perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to say but a scope is an object and an object can be made the scope for a function. As for the second part, are you familiar with `Function.prototype.bind()`? That does exactly that, it sets `this` to some object for a function. Or for immediate calling with `Function.prototype.apply()` and `Function.prototype.call()`.

Comment: @Wolph well in JavaScript "scope" generally refers to a lexical context - the space in which `var` variables exist. In that sense a scope is *like* an object, but there's no way to explicitly refer to a scope. Thus, a function declared locally (inside another function) is associated with that scope, but it is not associated with any object (unless explicitly made a property value of some object).

Comment: @Wolph: "every javascript is bound to some scope, therefore making it a method", i don't think your conclusion follows. methods belong to an object, and scope is not an object, even though _with_ can fake it going to other way. scope also has nothing to do with _this_ or _fn.bind()_, which are not affected by scope (expect ES6 fat arrows). the "scope" of a method is simply the local, psuedo-global, and global variables that the function can see at the time it was defined, and thus cannot be altered post-definition.

Comment: @dandavis: That's simply semantics imho, would it make you happy if I did a s/scope/object/g?

Comment: @Wolph:  saying "scope is an object and an object can be made the scope" goes beyond semantics and demonstrates a lack of distinction in  scope vs _this_ binding, or implies certain behind the scenes facts that may or may not be true in a given engine. given that js is an object reference capability language, not having a reference to an object (if scope was indeed an "internal" object) means that, essentially, there is no object.

Comment: That's actually the essentials of most object oriented programming, this discussion is starting to go into semantics which do not interest me much. Please provide some reference or example proving your point of you would like to continue this discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Technicaly, javascript does not have methods in the technical object-oriented way. Instead uses the prototype model of object inheritance (for example javascript does not have class inheritance but prototypical inheritance, does not support private methods etc etc, these are differences between the two models, e.g "Javascript, the good parts").

Anyway, any function added as property of an object can be called as the object's method e.g `obj.my_method()` and also `this` inside the function will dynamicaly have access to the current `object`

Another way to call a function *as if it is a method* is by using `.call` functionality. For example `my_method.call(obj)` This is also an alternative to having private methods in javascript. One can define a function which is not accessible as the object property, but can be called as if it is a method of the object, using `.call` to bind `this` inside the function to the current object. One can argue that any function when called this way (or similarly) is indeed a `method`, i will not argue about it nor say otherwise.

Mumbling about terminology is not coding. Have fun

Comment: "Technicaly javascript does not have methods in the object-oriented way" Sorry, I don't believe this to be correct, so I down-voted.

Comment: @BenAston, why believe when you can test? ;) anyway i wouldnt accept the downvote as explained , but i'll be nice

Comment: @BenAston, for example javascript does not have class\ inheritance but prototypical inheritance, does not support private methods etc etc. These are differences between the object-oriented model and the prototypical model. You can read all about it in e.g "Javascript the good parts"

Comment: I've read it! My understanding is that a method is a function associated with an  object, that when invoked is run against said object by default. I believe the Wikipedia entry on methods to be incomplete in that it only covers class-based languages. Alan Kay, when defining his invention OO made no reference to classes.

Comment: @BenAston, your understanding of a method is correct, but this is not the technical object-oriented method you are refering, but it is similar in some respects

Comment: @NikosM. : who says a method has to be inherited or private to be a method? "class inheritance but prototypical inheritance" and no "private methods" are differences, sure, but that (or any other divergences) alone don't mean that Math.max() is not a method.